# Any reason not to omit "only screen" from media queries nowadays?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm working with Laravel/Vue and my projects don't seem to be compatible with IE anyway so I was wondering if I could reduce:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px)
```

to just:

```
@media (max-width: 576px)
```

Is there any downside to this except that older (ancient) browsers will break my site?

Comment: I always omit it, if it affects print that's fine because it will still look fine and web applications are mostly not meant to be printed.

Comment: @KareemKamal And then when one wants to print it, what happens?

Comment: it prints normally, if the paper size in pixels matches the rule the CSS applies, just like window sizes

Comment: Why do you think it will break older browsers? The syntax is pretty clear, it just means the style will apply to any media with the given width, rather than being limited to screens. Are you expecting users to use non-screen media?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using `only screen` is used in media queries to prevent older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the specified styles.

To block older browsers from seeing the stylesheet, you will write:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:630px){ ... }
```